# -[__NSDictionaryI name]: unrecognized selector in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

-[__NSDictionaryI name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae38527a80
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae38527a80' 
![enter image description here][1]

```
imageid = @"ImageID";
        name = @"Name";
        path = @"Path";
        // And add a few recipes to it
        recipes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
        Recipe* recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];


    //        recipe.name = @"Image 1";
    //        recipe,path = @"http://absolutesoft.net/test/ios/col/img/img1.png";
    //        recipe.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image 2"];
    //        [recipes addObject:recipe];



            NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://absolutesoft.net/test/ios/col/getImages.php"]];

            id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

            // values in foreach loop
            for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {


                recipe.image = [dataDict objectForKey:@"ImageID"];;
                recipe.name = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Name"];
                recipe.Path = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Path"];
                NSLog(@"recipe.image %@",recipe.image);
                NSLog(@"recipe.name %@",recipe.image);
                NSLog(@"recipe.Path %@",recipe.Path);

                dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        recipe.image, imageid,
                        recipe.name, name,
                        recipe.Path, path,
                        nil];
                [recipes addObject:dict];
            }
            //NSLog(@"Dict = %@",dict);
        NSLog(@"recipes = %@",recipes);
```

Comment: Please add a proper problem description. Just posting an error message won't get you any help.

Comment: What makes you think `jsonObjects` is an `NSDictionary`?

Answer (score 1):

You're making the assumption that your call here:

```
        id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

did not fail. Don't pass nil to the error parameter. Pass a real NSError and check the value.

Comment: Can i making the assumption that me call here
[recipes addObject:dict];
NSLog(@"recipes = %@",recipes);

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ow5fjwkbz84lnb8/Code%20iOS.zip?dl=0

Please..

Comment: No, you cannot make that assumption until you KNOW that recipies is an NSDictionary. One easy way to be sure is to check the error parameter.